# Ubuntu on old Macs - does it stop the "planned obsolescence" slowdown inherent on the software or is it a hardware issue?

Tags: mac

Everytime I encounter an older Mac, it has a ton of problems with the software, most notably incompatibility with new Mac updates and major battery usage and slowdown problems. Would installing Ubuntu on older Macs fix this or is the slowdown and error stuff built into the hardware?

Comment: I don't see how this question fits this site's on-topic rules (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as it's very opinion oriented and thus better suited to a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/) rather than this Q&A format.  In reply Lubuntu runs great on this 2009 dell I'm using (*where I'm not sure I'd be saying the same if it was still running windows but that's off-topic opinion too*)  This is a Ubuntu site, nor a hardware Q&A site, nor forum.

Answer (score 0):

Old HDDs become slow, and old batteries lose their ability to store energy. I don't think other components of a computer would have planned obsolescence built into them.

### 4 GB or greater memory (Intel Macs)

If you have enough memory, any recent version of Ubuntu should run well on an Intel Macs.

### 2 GB or less memory (Intel Macs)

If you have 2 GB memory or less, you should stick to a variant like Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.
Alternatively, unless you need to regularly connect it to the internet, you can also use a slightly older version of Ubuntu (or its flavors).

### PowerPC 64 bit

Ubuntu does not officially support PowerPC. Use [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) instead.

### 32 bit Intel Macs

Since recent versions of Ubuntu has dropped support for 32 bit processors, you can either stick to Lubuntu/Xubuntu 18.04 (not anymore supported), or use Debian.

Comment: Flavors of 18.04 have reached EoL (3 years of support only). Debian, AntiX, etc. is the way moving forward in 32-bit.

Comment: The last Debian to support PPC (& not *ppc64el*) was Debian 8/Jessie (https://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/) which reached EOL on 30-June-2020 (https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) so you do realize you're suggesting an EOL/unsupported system

Comment: @guiverc Does any popular distro support 32 bit powerpc anymore?

Comment: Sorry I don't know... I'm involved only with Debian (news) & Ubuntu (news & flavor), and whilst I use Fedora & OpenSuSE it's for bug confirmation purposes primarily related to the Ubuntu *flavor*.